# Python serialize namedtuple key in dictionary to json

Tags: python, json, namedtuple

```
FB = namedtuple(“FB”, (“foo”,”bar”))
fb = FB(123, 456)
test_dict={fb:999}
```

How to serialize to json for test_dict?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve in your example code? What is `namedtuple()`? Is it your own method or is it from an import (`collections` module maybe)?

Comment: you want to serialize `test_dict` to JSON?

Comment: oh, you want the namedtuple to be serialized as a dict (json object) instead of a list?